# Helpful directions when closing questions

Tags: discussion, architecture

This question, [How to implement multi-tenant billing in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195227/how-to-implement-multi-tenant-billing-in-azure) seems like a reasonable one for Stack Overflow to me, it's asking for architectural insight. 
But I'm not familiar with the nuances of a good Stack Overflow question these days. Thus, maybe it should be on another site. At one point, I think you used to get recommendations for which site a question belongs on. I don't see that here.
Since this is a new user, and I'm mindful of the moves being made to feel more welcome, shouldn't a close include a bit more information/

Comment: It was closed for the wrong reason.  But that tends to happen when a question is tremendously vague.  At no point does the OP explain where he got stuck.  It is a task description before it is a question, nobody should start programming from a functional description that only covers a single paragraph.  Or attempt to answer it.

Comment: It's not even a programming question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it definitely is, OP updated the question for clarity based on responses here.

Comment: @Irwin In other words, at the time of my comment, it was not a programming question?

Comment: Dude, I'm not here to win arguments. Take win. Have a good time.

Answer (score 13):

The impulse to try and help anyway by suggesting another place for a person to go ask their questions is a commendable one, but it is, alas, ultimately a mistake.

It is not the job of this website or its users to suggest where people should go to ask questions that we do not accept. Our job is merely to enforce our own scope. We are not experts on—and, indeed, may not even be knowledgeable about—the scope of other sites.

The only thing worse than closing a question without a recommendation of where else to go is a *wrong* recommendation of where to go. The person then tries to follow the recommendation, asks there, and has their question once again closed. That’s a terrible user experience, and all because they took advice from the people least qualified to give that advice.

Questions that are off-topic or otherwise unsuitable for Stack Overfow should just be closed. No “go here instead”, no “but maybe try this”, no apologies, no snark, no need for commentary of any kind.

Comment: What you're saying is fair, but I'd like to see some stats, if anyone has them, about what happens to users who ask questions on SE sites and are immediately downvoted and have their questions closed. 

Do they ever participate again? If I had to guess (and I don't actually have to guess in this particular case - I work with OP), after an initial negative experience, they're less likely to come back.

Comment: @RyanShripat Would you think it's *undesirable* that people posting inappropriate content on the site are less likely to come back than people posting high quality and desirable content?

Comment: True... but really difficult to actually follow up on.

Comment: @Servy that's a pretty black and white approach, isn't it? Wouldn't you rather we level them up by encouraging better content?


If you're saying that the resources don't exist to execute on this, I might agree, but you can't make a blanket statement that all 'undesirable' posters should never come back.

Comment: @RyanShripat I asked you if you think it's undesirable.  I made no such blanket statement.  Since you feel that we don't have the resources to ensure these users post quality content, why do you feel it's desirable for them to continue posting, given that you feel they're likely to continue posting problematic content?

Comment: I have ample empirical evidence that plenty of people who have questions closed come back to ask more questions.

Answer (score 6):

Thought I'd chime in, since I voted to close that question. The issue is that it's very broad and opinion-soliciting: there's simply no way to objectively answer it, since there are many ways to implement a billing system. And there is no specific programming question here. Such a question typically leads to opinions, discussion, and occasionally debate. Also note that the OP wasn't asking about a specific programming question related to an Azure billing service. This was a generic question about multi-tenancy and customer billing.

Per Hans' comment, I agree it was closed for the wrong reason (should've been 'too broad' 
 or 'opinion-soliciting', vs 'recommendation'). And, perhaps it would've been valuable for me to post a comment offering suggestions for the OP to improve the question (I typically do that, but I neglected to do so for this particular question).

I think the auto-generated reasons and explanations posted under the question, once closed, are fairly descriptive and non-confrontational. In this case, a better description would've been provided, had it been closed for a more accurate reason.

Comment: Whaddya know, you actually cast a vote to close as “too broad”. That specific reason got overridden when a moderator cast a binding vote atop a bunch of votes for a variety of different reasons. Meta has now reopened and reclosed as “too broad”. If it were me, I would have just closed as off-topic. I fail to see how this is at all related to programming.

Comment: @CodyGray billing can be a programming problem, not 100% sure it is always off-topic, as they state it is not about Azure billing but about an app they are hosting on Azure. I've opted for too broad, when I recycled that question in SOCVR.

Comment: @rene Billing is a programming problem when you’re implementing a billing system. Otherwise, it’s a customer support issue. This one definitely reads like a customer support issue to me.

Comment: @CodyGray fair enough. I can go with that explanation as well.

Comment: OP updated question based on feedback.